# Owner userRole name is not accessible

Tags: soql

Heyy All,

I was trying to pull the role name and tried following query -

```
Select id, owner.userRole.Name from opportunity where stagename = 'closedWon'
```

However when i try this simple query in developer console,  i found that role name is not shown.  Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how you are outputting the data. If you run this in the developer console you should see the role name displayed in the second part:

```
Opportunity[] opps = [Select Id, Owner.UserRole.Name from Opportunity];

// This only only shows the fields directly on Opportunity: Id and OwnerId
System.debug('>>> ' + opps);

for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
    // This tranverses the User and UserRole reference to output the Name
    System.debug('>>> ' + opp.Owner.UserRole.Name);
}
```

Comment: If i execute in query editor,  i dont get role name returned instead getting [object, object]

Comment: @Sara Yes the query editor is just displaying each field as a simple string so when the field is a reference to another object it displays "[object, object]" which is a default of JavaScript. Arguably its a bug in that part of the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

It works like @Keith said. Please check also that you have a role selected on the owner(s). Role is not mandatory, on my testOrg it was left empty... For debug outputs I created a little helper function to have quick dumps

```
public static void log(object o) {
System.debug(logginglevel.WARN, system.JSON.serializePretty(o));
}
```

saves you a lot time for sneak peaks...

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you install and use Ajax Tools (its a Freebie from Salesforce). Once you have it open, go to Explorer to construct your queries. It will default to 'limit 20' and won't give you the `where clause` option, but it seems to construct much better queries and provides better testing/validation that they work. Once you have the query, you can then easily run it from Eclipse.

A quick check here shows that Owner.UserRole theoretically can't be reached from Opportunity. UserRole is a parent of Owner which would be why your query is failing. That said, I plugged in your query and it did run (less the where clause) and returned results from within Ajax Tools.